# Python on Windows: How to mark a directory as a system folder

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way in Python 2.7 on Windows to mark a directory as a system folder?

(PS: I found the solution, see the answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked:

```
    import win32api, wind32con

    mydir ="Directory path goes here"
    win32api.SetFileAttributes(mydir,win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
```

Comment: You're missing the initial `GetFileAttributes` call to get the current attributes. Bitwise-or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` with the existing attributes. I also strongly recommend using Unicode with all Windows filesystem calls. Microsoft filesystems use UTF-16, so you don't want to be limited to ANSI.